# EJB: Mapping a DB column field to another field type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence, ejb

I have a DB table with a column with fieldtype INT, i want to map it to an EJB (Java Object), and use an Enum instead of int for that column/field. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums can mapped by there ordinal or name.

(Default Mapping is ordinal.)

```
enum Demo{ A, B};

@Entity
class MyEntity {
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private Demo demo;
}
```

So you can map an Enum to an integer Column.

Comment: what about @ColumnName annotation? where can i put it? under @Enumerated?

Comment: Dr.Lesh, you can add serveral annotations. For example @Enummerated, and @Column. The order of the annotations is not important.